# Creating a function and calling it from a UIButton connected to an IBAction?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have an iPhone app called i4MMS it is published in Cydia. I'm really a noob with this but I wanted to find a way to create a function or method and then call it using IBAction. Would it be like this?

```
+ (void) myMethod {
NSLog(@"Step 1");
NSLog(@"Step 2");
}

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
myMethod
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change
`myMethod` in your IBAction method
to
`[<insert name of class here> myMethod]`;

Comment: so something like this - (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
[homeViewController myMethod];
}